# im getting Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have searched about my problem in StackOverflow but didn't able to fix it myself self so I thought to post it here.

My problem is when I try to delete a Mainmenu in my app if there is a submenu belongs to that menu it doesn't allow us to delete it then backend will send nice error 400 msg also. 
but when I try to delete menu which doesn't have any child or any submenu it will delete it perfectly 
now the problem is my notification toast is calling two times when there's an error.it's showing error msg & also success msg.

i have added small gif file which is showing my error.

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvZJQ.jpg)

below is my redux action

```
//delete Menu
export const deleteMenu = (id) =>async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('action id : ' + id + '');
    await axios
        .delete(`/api/users/deleteMenu/${id}`)
        .then(
            (res) =>

                dispatch({
                    type: 'MENU_DELETED',
                    value: id
                }),
                dispatch(getMenu()),
                toast.success('Menu Deleted Successfully!')


        )
        .catch((err) => {
//below has a returnerror handler which i created is use to show errors when error is there.
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'MENU_DELETE_FAILED'));
            console.log(err);

        });
};
```

//get Menu action

```
export const getMenu = () => (dispatch) => {


    axios
        .get(`/api/users/getMenu`)
        .then((res) =>

            dispatch({
                type: 'GET_MENU',
                value: res.data
            })
        )
        .catch((err) => {

            console.log('Get Menu error! : ' + err);
        });
};
```

below is my backend

```
//delete Menu
router.delete('/deleteMenu/:id', (req, res) => {

    db.query('SELECT id FROM menu WHERE parentId =' + req.params.id + ' ', (error, hvchild) => {
        if (!error) {
            if (hvchild.length > 0) {
                return res.status(400).json("Please Delete Child Menu's Before Deleting Main Menu!");
            } else {
        console.log("im called")
                db.query('DELETE FROM menu WHERE id = ' + req.params.id + '', (err, row) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        res.json('Menu Deleted Successfully!');
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        }else{
      console.log(error);
    }
    });
});
```

Update: I have updated my code acording to Narendra Chouhan's answer.
now the problem is my notification toast is calling two times when there's an error.it's showing error msg & also success msg.

ps: im new to react & redux :)

Comment: `dispatch(toast.success('Menu Deleted Successfully!'))` this is wrong. `dispatch` takes an action `{type:foo, value:foobar}`

Comment: Not necessarily. If `getMenu()` returns an action there is no problem there

Comment: you can simply do `toast.success('Menu Deleted Successfully!')` to show a toast, if `getMenu()` doesn't return an `action` use it simply `getMenu()`.

Comment: @Dupocas yeah, but we don't know what `getMenu()` returns.

Comment: any help guys :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//delete Menu
export const deleteMenu = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log('action id : ' + id + '');
  await axios
    .delete(`/api/users/deleteMenu/${id}`)
    .then(
      (res) =>

        dispatch({
          type: 'MENU_DELETED',
          value: { id }
        }),
      dispatch(getMenu())
        toast.success('Menu Deleted Successfully!'),


    )
    .catch((err) => {
      //below has a returnerror handler which i created is use to show errors when error is there.
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'MENU_DELETE_FAILED'));
      console.log(err);

    });
};
```

try this, it will work for you

Comment: Yes, this seems the right way, to use `value : {id}`. +1

Comment: Thank you for your Help! i have changed the code according to you followed..

Comment: now the problem is my notification toast is calling two times when there's an error.it's showing error msg & also success msg. if you don't mind please check this small gif file showing the problem: https://imgur.com/jCKbwy2

Comment: any help guys :(

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it my self Thak you All your help!

what is did was

```
//delete Menu
export const deleteMenu = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    console.log('action id : ' + id + '');
    await axios
        .delete(`/api/users/deleteMenu/${id}`)
        .then(
            (res) =>
///below i added 2 braces covering dispatch & toast & then removed the comma's which i ///used earlier .
            {dispatch({
                type: 'MENU_DELETED',
                value:{ id }
            })
            dispatch(getMenu())
            toast.success('Menu Deleted Successfully!')
                }




        )
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'MENU_DELETE_FAILED'));
            console.log(err);

        });
};
```